# uploading image in Django inside a for loop

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-media

I wanted show the uploaded image from admin url in my index.html template. so i needed to put a for loop and I got a probelm in image src.

setting.py :

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static"
]
```

models.py :

```
class Home(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = "static")
    titr = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated = models.DateField(auto_now = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']        

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.titr)
```

views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Home

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    home = Home.objects.all()
    context = {"homes" : home}
    return render(request, 'home/index.html', context)
```

index.html(doesn't work) :

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}

{% for home in homes %}
<br>
<h1>{{home.titr}}</h1>
<img src="{% static '{{home.image.url}}' %}" style="width:50%" alt="My image">
<p>{{home.description}}</p>
<br><hr>
{% endfor %}


{% endblock content %}
```

index.html(work but it's not what i want):

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}

{% for home in homes %}
<br>
<h1>{{home.titr}}</h1>
<img src="{% static '{{home.image.url}}' %}" style="width:50%" alt="My image">
<p>{{home.description}}</p>
<br><hr>
{% endfor %}


{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: `work but it's not what i want` This doesn't tell us much.  Show us what the code _actually does_, and explain how that's different from what you _wanted_.

Comment: sorry i forget to change the second one. i mean this --> <img src="{% static 'image.jpg' %}" style="width:50%" alt="My image">. i can see the image this way but i want to put it into a for loop . thnx

Comment: `ImageField` content is not `static` it's `media`. Remove all the `static` stuff around `{{ home.image.url }}`

Comment: `ImageField(upload_to = "static")` no, don't mix media files with static files, choose different folder.

Comment: `<img src="{% static '{{home.image.url}}' %}"` Since you're already inside `{% %}` brackets, you don't need the `{{ }}` ones.  I don't think you need the quotes either. Try this instead: `<img src="{% static home.image.url %}"`